# Is there any point to stack Tougher Times past 7?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

[image]

The teddy bear item adds 15% block chance per stack.  This means that at 7 stacks, you'll hit 100+% block chance.  Unlike the Lens-Maker's Glasses, the additional sentence at the end has me wondering what it means.

It says "Unaffected by Luck". But if you block all damage 100% of the time, wouldn't it render the rest of the game pointless since you can no longer take damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, but you'll need around ~6k to get close to 100%.

Doing some research, it turns out that the 1st teddy bear you get adds a flat 15% block chance, but each additional bear after is not actually additive, but multiplicative.

The datamined equation is: (1 - 1 / (0.15 * n + 1)), where n is the number of Tougher Times you have. The graph below from the [datamined source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11_SLL3ciUtcOx9j7BnFRbQ36A2UxvyGt1iJO8tF0wkM/edit#gid=0) showcases that in effect:

[image]

Basically, you'll need to stack ludicrous amounts to come close to 100% chance, but no matter the amount of teddy bears, 100% block chance can't actually be achieved.

Comment: Still, it's way more effective than the hermits scarf from the first game.